# Don't blow away comment box until success is assured

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

I can't describe how many times I've entered a comment, submitted, and had the submission fail for some unknown reason.  This wouldn't be a big deal, except it destroys the comment box, and everything in it, so everything I've typed is gone.

It's gotten to the point that I try to remember to do a copy of the box before I submit, but when I've typed a lengthy comment, it can be very frustrating to have it disappear completely, destroyed by a cat saying "it's not your fault".  Small consolation.

Would it be possible to not erase the comments field until the comment has successfully been submitted...an error report would just be appended into the page, rather than replacing the comment box.

Not sure about the feasibility/ease of this, or how many people it would help...but it drives me batty.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I just tested failing to post a comment (by disabling my network adapter), and the comment text box didn't disappear after the error message.

Comment: @Jon: I'm using IE 8.  I suspect that it's not the entire submission process that fails, but some aspect of it after it has partially succeeded.  (That's just an semi-educated guess, based on what I'm seeing.)

Comment: That's possible. The error I got says "An error occurred during comment submission". If the error message you're getting is the more generic one (something like "An error occurred" and that's it), then it may indicate a more low-level problem that is localized to your setup or configuration.

Comment: I have the same problem. I too have made it a habit to copy the comment before submission. My feeling is that it happens when I have spent a long time composing the comment (usually looking up a link or some other info).

Comment: Oddly, when I get the more common "An error occurred during comment submission" error, this still often (but not always) occurs.  My suspicion is that it depends on when in the process it fails (because otherwise the comment box should either always disappear or always remain...which doesn't seem to be the case.)

Comment: @Nifle: This makes sense to me...I've noticed the same thing...though it could just be my mind playing tricks.

Comment: This has happened sometimes to me when the connection timeouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably XSRF related. If your network connection is bad enough, this is inevitable, but we have made improvements so that it should be quite rare (or your internet connection is *really* bad).

see:
[Blank page when adding a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48711/blank-page-when-adding-a-comment)