# Blank page when adding a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

I am sometimes getting a blank page when I am submitting a comment.  I am using Vista and Google Chrome.

I suspect this is related to other errors I am experiencing with [editing posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47082/i-am-getting-oops-something-bad-happened-quite-often-while-editing-posts) and [voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46989/an-error-has-occurred-please-retry-your-request-while-voting).

I do not have consistent steps to reproduce this behavior. This does not happen every time. It would be nice if the system could catch this and provide more user friendly error message.

Comment: The whole page goes blank?

Comment: @mmyers: Yes, the whole page.

Comment: Chrome gives me random problems but not with StackOverflow, other sites, and only on my home computer.

Comment: Happens to me all the time in Chrome. I try to remember copying my comment to the clipboard before submitting. I usually don't.

Comment: Disable all Chrome plugins/extensions and retry.

Comment: I do not have any extension or plugins installed.

Comment: First character of the comment is `@`? Juha

Comment: This seems to be related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47405/add-comment-fails-never-posting-comment

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us consistent repro steps? We can't reproduce this.

(as per the other linked questions, it's likely XSRF key failure due to network conditions.)

edit: We did find a small bug that might have caused this in rare circumstances, for users who tend to switch IP addresses rapidly. Let us know if it's any better after today (May 14 '10).

Comment: I still got this error when commenting.

Comment: Same, 8 years after the original post.